# Linq Query for most occuring property of a class

Tags: c#, database, linq

I know this is really basic but how do I implement a linq query that returns the most occuring field?

This is what I got so far:

```
var commonAge = from c in customers.GroupBy(s=>s.age)
                                   .OrderByDescending(sg=>sg.Count())
                                   .Take(1)
                select s.Key;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you give us more details: the code you have so far, what have you tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is what I got so far.
var commonAge = from c in customers
                               .GroupBy(s=>s.age)
                               .OrderByDescending(sg=>sg.Count())
                               .Take(1)
                               select s.Key;

Comment: You should at least show what your data look like, what do you want by sample output etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you are looking for the most common `Age` on a customer data type which has said property.

```
// Start with the customers collection
var mostCommonAge = customers
// then group by their age, 
    .GroupBy(c => c.Age,
// and project into a new anonymous type
        (key, g) => new {Age = key, Count = g.Count()})
// order by count of each age
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count)
// and take the first
    .First();
```

---

Here's a complete working example. With a data model class `Customer`:

```
class Customer {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get;set; }
}
```

Then you can output the most common age by

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var customers = new List<Customer> { 
        new Customer { Age = 23 }, 
        new Customer { Age = 23 }, 
        new Customer { Age = 23 }, 
        new Customer { Age = 24 }, 
        new Customer { Age = 25 } 
        };

    var mostCommonAge = customers
        .GroupBy(c => c.Age,
            (key, g) => new {Age = key, Count = g.Count()})
        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count)
        .First();

    Console.WriteLine(mostCommonAge);

}
```